# Hindsight Experience Replay (HER) results obtained 50 times faster than original paper?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am reproducing the results from Hindsight Experience Replay by Andrychowicz et. al. In the original paper they present the results below, where the agent is trained for 200 epochs.

200 epochs * 800 episodes * 50 time steps = 8,000,000 total time steps.

[image]

I try to reproduce the results but instead of using 8 cpu cores, I am using 16 CPU cores.

---

### Fetch Push

I train the `FetchPush` for 80 epochs, but with only 50 episodes per epoch. Therefore 80 * 50 * 50 = 200,000 iterations. I present the curve below, generated using **two random seeds**.

After 20 epochs = 50,000 iterations we solve this environment. In the paper above, it took the original authors 100 episodes = 4,000,000 iterations to do so.

How is my algorithm converging **50 times faster**?

[image]

---

### Pick and Place

I train the `FetchPickAndPlace` for 80 epochs, but with only 50 episodes per epoch. Therefore 80 * 50 * 50 = 200,000 iterations. I present the curve below, generated using **three random seeds**:

[image]

and logger output for the first two epochs, showing that indeed I have 50 episodes per epoch:

[image]

Now, as can be seen from my tensorboard plot, after 40 epochs we get a steady success rate, close to 1. 40 epochs * 50 episodes * 50 time steps = 100,000 iterations. Therefore it took the algorithm approximately 100,000 time steps to learn this environment.

The original paper took approximately 50 * 800 * 50 = 2,000,000 time steps to achieve the same goal.

How is it that in my case the environment was solved nearly **20 times faster**? Are there any flaws in my workings above? Surely I am doing something wrong, right?

Results are also faster than another paper which also uses 19 MPI workers:

[image]

As stated in this paper: "We train for  50 epochs (one epoch consists of 19  2  50 = 1 900 full episodes), which amounts to a total of 4.75 x10^6 timesteps." It took around 2,000,000 timesteps to reach a median success rate of 0.9.

---

### SUMMARY

[image]

---

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong would be appreciated.

[Code](https://github.com/RyanRizzo96/RL_baselines)
[Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/f4uv2p/how_are_my_hindsight_experience_replay_her/)

---

### EDIT - Logging

Logging process shows that the rank 0 worker is reporting results. Inside `her.py`)

```
   if rank == 0:
        logger.dump_tabular()
```

The function responsible for writing all diagnostics is `dumpkvs()` inside `logger.py`:

```
def dumpkvs():
    """
    Write all of the diagnostics from the current iteration
    """
    Logger.CURRENT.dumpkvs()
```

Code can be found here:

https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/logger.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reading the results incorrectly.

```
1 epoch = 50 episodes = 2500 timesteps
50 epochs = 2500 episodse = 125,000 timesteps
125,000*16 CPU cores = 2 million time steps.
```

Will give a more detailed answer later.